# Google places Javascript API to suggest countries?

Tags: google-places-api

Is it possible to return countries with JavaScript places API ? For e.g I want to be able to search for countries like United States. Is it possible to get suggestions for countries  in  autocomplete field ? How do I do it ?

Comment: So, someone has been voting down all my recent questions sequentially! Can understand!:)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `(regions)` type in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete).  I think that's the best you can do, for now.